# Slow indexing and lower rankings on ccTLD vs TLD domain

Tags: google, domains, google-search, opencart

Recently I have decided to move my site form a .rs domain to a .com one. With that I also upgraded my software (OpenCart 1.5 to 2.0).
Both the .com and .rs sites are currently operational. What I have noticed that in a matter of days Google has indexed the .com version of the site and in most cases is ranking it higher than the .rs one that has been operational for some two years.

I am confused to why this has happened, is it related to the domain, or does it have to do with the new software? I am pretty new to SEO and this has me puzzled.

Comment: These answers may help clarify things for you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78675/how-bad-would-it-be-to-use-a-cctld-domain-on-a-website-targeted-to-another-count/78676#78676 http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/local-tld-vs-com-and-com-nl-vs-nl/86268#86268

Answer (score 1):

I have always seen That Google doesn't make differences between `.com` and `.foobar`, but users **make** the difference. All end users know `.com` TLD and are familiar with it, but not everyone know that something ending with `.rs` could be a website.

The fact that you see an increment in your website ranking probably relates to the new software, and may be people visit it more often or link your site more with that familiar domain.

Google confirms this in the article [Google's handling of new top level domains](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html):

> Q: Will Google support my SEO efforts to move my domain from .com to a
> new TLD? How do I move my website without losing any search ranking or
> history?
>
> A: We have extensive site move documentation in our Help
> Center. We treat these moves the same as any other site move. That
> said, domain changes can take time to be processed for search (and
> outside of search, users expect email addresses to remain valid over a
> longer period of time), so it's generally best to choose a domain that
> will fit your long-term needs.

Comment: I guessed it was probably the software. Thanks alot for the clarification.