# Redirecting a gTLD to a ccTLD to increase traffic

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, top-level-domains, cctld

I have a very short and fancy ccTLD (`vwx.yz`) for my private page. The page gives an overview about me and my conducted research and is currently associated with some small island somwhere nowhere.

I also have the gTLD (`complicated_name.com` and `comlicated_name.de`). However, for the sake of spelling and memorising, I would like to stick to `vwx.yz` as my main page and channel all the traffic there.

## Issues

- The ccTLD is not yet considered generic by [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399) (although I think that might change some time).
- I cannot find my private page on Google (UK, DE, US) with keywords usually leading to my research. In fact, I am at position 30 when googling for my own name.

## Questions

- In [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/78683/60579) it is claimed that redirecting a gTLD to ccTLD might have an effect for SEO, are there any sources for that?
- Should I first copy the hole contact to `complicated_name.com` for the language English (with a link stating the canonical page is `vwx.yz`), let google index it and than do a 301 redirect from `complicated_name.com` to `vwx.yz`? (Same for `complicated_name.de` -> `vwx.yz/de`)

Comment: It all depends upon who you are targeting and where they are.

Comment: It is about research, so I target researchers. The scientific language is mostly English. I am not interested in targeting a specific country, although I coded this maybe implicitly in the issues *"(UK, DE, US)"*.

Comment: I am not a geo-targeting expert, however, it seems that a .com would allow you to reach all three easier. However, using google.com(munist) should show the ccTLDs for UK and DE just fine. I still think the .com would do better. If this is what you are thinking, put your content on the .com, redirect your ccTLDs to .com. Once the redirects are all seen by G, you can remove the ccTLDs if you are not too worried about link values. Otherwise, leave them. All this can be reversed if necessary. Of course it all takes time. Cheers!!

Comment: I imagine that your research and anyone looking at it and information about you is quite specific, so SEO may not be so important.  If they are looking up Marcus + your research speciality, it will probably be a short list of results so it may not be a battle to be at the top.

Oh...didn't realise this was so old...community bumped it :P

Answer (score -1):

If Google doesn't list the country code TLD as "generic", then it won't rank outside its country.   If you move your content to the ccTLD you will lose all your Google rankings and traffic.  It doesn't matter if you use redirects or canonicals, Google won't show pages from most ccTLDs in global search.

I think this is really stupid behavior from Google, but it has been this way for years without a good work around.